# Remove lowest color from colorbar in Seaborn/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

If I set `shade_lowest = False`, the colorbar still contains the lowest level (purple-ish). Is there any generic way to remove it entirely?

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
b = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.kdeplot(a, b, shade = True, shade_lowest = False, cmap = "viridis", cbar = True, n_levels = 4, ax = ax)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is for sure to not create this level from the beginning.

Here we choose maximally 5 levels according to a locator and remove the lowest one when calling the `contourf` plot, such that this level does not even exist in the first place. Then the automatic colorbar creation works flawlessly.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(5)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
from scipy import stats

x = np.random.normal(3, 1, 100)
y = np.random.normal(0, 2, 100)
X, Y = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():100j, y.min():y.max():100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(),Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([x,y])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

N=4
locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(N + 1, min_n_ticks=N)
lev = locator.tick_values(Z.min(), Z.max())


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,levels=lev[1:])
ax.scatter(x,y, s=9, c="k")
fig.colorbar(c)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great method! Why is Z being transposed, and then transposed again? Not sure I follow the math at work here.

Comment: Ups, that may be my fault, I did not verify if the data is actually correct, this is to show the general method - will have a look in a minute.

Comment: Looks to me like neither of them are required, when plotting scatter on top :)

Comment: I updated the code (using asymmetric x and y), it should now be correct.